# How to apply the font color in conditional statement

Tags: php, html, css

I want to change the  'Not Activated' font to be red.

```
$status=($uid!="") ? 'Activated' : 'Not Activated'."<br>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
$status = ($uid!="") ? '<span style="color: green">Activated</span>' : '<span style="color: red">Not Activated</span>'."<br>";
```